# Classify the singularities (removable, pole and essential)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laurent-series

> I have to classify the singularities (removable, pole and essential) of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$.

I know that $e^z-1=0 \iff e^z=1 \iff z = 2\pi k i$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there an easy to find out all type of singularity without passing through the Laurent series directly? **(Please explain in details.)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, the expression
$$ \frac{z-2\pi ik}{e^z-1} $$
is the reciprocal of the quotient which appears in the definition of the derivative of $e^z$ at $z=2\pi ik$. Since this derivative is equal to $1$, it follows that
$$\lim_{z\to 2\pi ik}\frac{z-2\pi ik}{e^z-1}=1 $$
hence $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ has a simple pole at $2\pi ik$.

Comment: I am not so good with the notion of classification of singularities. I don't understand at all what you did. Could you explain to me in details please? Why do you take the derivative? Why do you use $\lim_{z\to 2\pi ik}\frac{z-2\pi ik}{e^z-1}=1$ to conclude? How do you get $\frac{z-2\pi ik}{e^z-1}$?

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{|e^z-1|}\to\infty$ as $z\to 2\pi ik$, there must be a pole. The question is what is the order of the pole. This can be found by finding the minimal $m$ such that $\frac{(z-2\pi ik)^m}{e^z-1}$ is holomorphic near $2\pi ik$, and the limit computation shows that $m=1$ works.

Comment: Why do you think in term of the limit? I don't understand why $\frac{1}{|e^z-1|}\to\infty$ as $z\to 2\pi ik$, there must be a pole? Which result allow you this fact?

Comment: That's one way to define a pole: $f(z)$ has a pole at $z_0$ if  $z_0$ is an isolated singularity and $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=\infty$.

Comment: I lot of books have as defintion : The singularity $z_0$ is a pole, of ordre $k$ iif $a_{-k} \not=0$ and $a_n=0$ for all $n < -k$. Could you tell me why both definitions are equivalent?

Comment: Using your definition, you can write $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}$ near $z_0$, with $g(z)$ holomorphic and $g(z_0)\neq 0$. Then what is $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|$?

Answer (score 1):

The series expansion for $e^z - 1$ is
$$ e^z - 1 = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j!}
$$
so it has a simple zero (divide by $z$ to see this) at every $z = 2\pi i k$ by the periodicity of $\exp$. Hence the reciprocal $\frac{1}{e^z - 1}$ has a simple pole at every $z = 2\pi i k$.

Comment: Which step does you not understand?

Comment: Do you know how to obtain the series expansion for $e^z -1$?

Comment: So which part does you not understand?

Comment: Let do it, I'll do it another way. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i am replying on a mobile device and it is difficult to read mathjax there.